# Use multiple selects instead of union in hibernate table per class inheritence

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0

I am using TABLE_PER_CLASS inheritance.  I have an abstract parent class that is an @Entity and multiple (~ a dozen) classes that extend the parent that are @Entity.

The class that references this abstract entity is marked with Fetch Lazy.

Everything functions but hibernate uses an extremely large query that unions all the tables together.

Is it possible to have hibernate use multiple select statements instead of this complicated union?  If we keep adding children we possibly hit some performance issues and have to rewrite

Comment: Are you querying based on the subclasses or is the query trying to return all of type parent class?

Comment: There is a class that has a OneToMany relationship to the parent Entity.  So I believe it queries on the parent.

Comment: There's the problem.  If the reference is just to type parentEntity then Hibernate will have to search all the subclasses for the matching one (i.e. all the tables)

Comment: Yes, I don't mind it doing that.  My preference would be that it use multiple select statements instead of one large union.  So far it doesn't seem configurable...

Comment: It shouldn't be a necessity though. If you find yourself in a case where you require a large number of children in the union, you might want to revisit your class hierarchy. In the general case, it tends to be a design smell. That's been my experience, so of course, YMMV.

Comment: Yes at some point we'd have to consider composition over inheritance, we're exploring our options.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK unions are multiple selects, the results are just concated and returned as one resultset instead of multiple resultsets.

Comment: Exactly. Moreover, most SQL dialects provide a `DISTINCT` modifier to the `UNION` clause to ensure the result of the concatenations is free of duplicates (making this a `union` in the true set theoretical sense... and which is what most people typically want out of a SQL UNION.)

Comment: I would like hibernate to produce and execute N sql statements where N is the number of entities I have instead of 1 sql statement with N unions.

Comment: i don't know any way to configure this and i think there is none because it doesn't affect performance at all. the fetch plan is the same, the resultset is the same, only the jdbc code to get the results looks a bit different.

Answer (score 2):

the difference is that when running this using the union (TABLE_PER_CLASS inheritance) , our query would like the following
select a, b, c from (select a, b, c from table1 union select a, b, c from table2) where ....

meaning if we have a very big table/tables (f.e 5 million records each), and the where clause should return only 5 records from each table for example, then although we will receive 10 records in the result, and with correct index the result per table should have returned very fast, the calculation of the union will analyze all 10 million results before returning only the relevant 10 (plus our indexes won't be used since the where clause is not on the table, but on the union result

Comment: This is exactly the problem that I am having. My query is the simplest: find by ID! Unfortunately, it still unions all the tables together and THEN use the criteria. That is too heavy. I'm tempted to use JOIN_TABLE for this ...

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to have hibernate use multiple select statements
>   instead of this complicated union? If we keep adding children we
>   possibly hit some performance issues and have to rewrite

That is what we faced, on production. :) We noticed the performance was slowing down as the data grew bigger - we knew we had to shift to the `JOINED` strategy. Simple `em.find(...)` calls were causing that nasty UNION you pasted.

Using `@Inheritance(JOINED)` did the trick - the generated DDL's are way much neater (and faster):

```
SELECT 
  _p.id, ..., 
  _a.id, ..., 
  _b.id, ... 
  FROM parent AS _p 
    INNER JOIN child_a AS _a on _p.id=_a.id 
    INNER JOIN child_b AS _b on _p.id=_b.id 
  WHERE _p.id= '...';
```

That would use the table's own primary keys, so it's guaranteed to be fast.